# unable to select element from custom alert using appium and webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, ionic2, appium, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I am working on automation testing, for that i have used webdriver.io and appium. i want to select element from the custom alert which is having list of radio button, when i used waitForExist for the element which i want to choose then i got response true, but when i tried to click on that element then i got error **Error: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters ("//*[@id="alert-input-0-0"]")**, i have created custom alert in ionic 2 which is below...

```
var options = {
      title: 'SortBy',
      inputs: [],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Ok',
          handler: data => {

          }
        }
      ]
    };

    options.inputs = [];


    for (let i = 0; i < this.sortOpts.length; i++) {
      options.inputs.push({ value: i, label: this.sortOpts[i], type: 'radio', checked: this.checkedSort[i] });
    }

    // Create the alert with the options
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create(options);
    alert.present();
```

and the test case is below...

```
client.waitForExist('//*[@id="alert-input-0-0"]', 20000, true) 
       .then(function () {
          console.log("exits....")

          client.element('//*[@id="alert-input-0-0"]')
          .click()                                            
          .then(function () {

                console.log("cliked....")
          })
         .catch(function (err) {
                console.log("Error received: >>>>>> " + err);
          })
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
         console.log("Error received: >>>>>> " + err);
    })
```

but unable to click  on first option from radio group list and getting error as above. can anyone help me to solve this?